# div does not resize when nested elements wrap

Tags: html, css

I have a label and a text box inside a div, which should be sized to fit the contents and centered in the window. When the windows is wide enough, they should be in columns. When the window is too narrow, they should be stacked. The inner items wrap as the window resizes, but at the point where the text box wraps, the div does not resize. What's wrong?

```
<style>
    label {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 10em;
    }
    input {
        max-width: 98%;
        width: 20em;
    }
    div.form-wrapper {
        background-color: red;
        display: table;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding: .4em;
        width: auto;
    }
</style>
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <label for="Player">Player's name</label>
    <input id="Player" type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is the built in behavior. Unfortunately I believe the only work around is to use javascript, which is likely more than you're looking to do for such a small issue. If you're looking to fix it with js, you can [take a look at this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yXxD6/55/), it may help

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have a floated element. If you remove the float then it will resize. Here is an example using media queries to remove the float on smaller screen sizes

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/2707/

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px)  {
  label {
    float: none;  
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you synchronize the media query width when the label and text box widths are dynamic?